# Angular: How to drop a line in an array in HTML?

Tags: angular

for exmple:[image]

Where I marked I want to go down a line.
I have an array of userName, Password errors.

component.ts:

```
 errors:string[] = []

  signUp(){
    this.usersService.Register(this.signupForm.value)
    .subscribe((res) => {

  this.signupForm.reset();
  this.router.navigate(['login']);
  
},(e)=> {
  if (e.error) {
    this.errors = [];
    this.errors.push(e.error);
  }

  if (e.error.errors?.Password) {
    this.errors = [];
    this.errors.push(e.error.errors?.Password);
  } 
  if (e.error.errors?.UserName) {
    this.errors.push(e.error.errors?.UserName);
  }
})
```

}

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let error of errors;" class="error">
                            
     {{error}}
                           
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think on your class CSS error you can make the display is block, that make every data error in the new row.

Comment: I solved it another way I added to the array like this:
              **this.errors.push (e.error? .errors? .Password [0]);
              this.errors.push (e.error? .errors? .Password [1]);**

But thanks so much for the help